# Jacoco - "Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_6da5971.Offline"

Tags: maven, jacoco, maven-surefire-plugin, jacoco-maven-plugin

Trying to get coverage via jacoco using offline instrumentation (can't use on-the-fly instrumentation: due to powermock testcases) for a maven project.Added the jacocoagent.jar to classpath in surefire plugin as shown below. Renamed the "org.jacoco.agent-0.7.7.201606060606-runtime.jar" (from local maven repository) to "jacocoagent.jar" and kept that in the same folder where this pom.xml is residing.I'm hitting the below exception even after adding it to classpath.

**snippet of pom.xml (surefire - plugin configuration)**

```
       <plugin>
             <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
             <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
             <configuration>
                     <forkmode>once</forkmode>
                    <additionalClasspathElements>
            <additionalClasspathElement>jacocoagent.jar</additionalClasspathElement>
                                        </additionalClasspathElements>
              </configuration>
     </plugin>
```

**Exception seen on console:**

```
#############
Number of foreign imports: 1
import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]

-----------------------------------------------------

        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:166)
        ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jacoco/agent/rt/internal_6da5971/Offline
        at com.cisco.ise.ups.modelframework.hibernate.OracleNamingStrategy.$jacocoInit(OracleNamingStrategy.java)
        at com.cisco.ise.ups.modelframework.hibernate.OracleNamingStrategy.<clinit>(OracleNamingStrategy.java)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorFactory.newFieldAccessor(UnsafeFieldAccessorFactory.java:43)
        at sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newFieldAccessor(ReflectionFactory.java:142)
        at java.lang.reflect.Field.acquireFieldAccessor(Field.java:1082)
        at java.lang.reflect.Field.getFieldAccessor(Field.java:1063)
        at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:387)
        at com.cisco.ise.ups.build.WorkflowRunnerMojo.namingStrategyInstance(WorkflowRunnerMojo.java:335)
        at com.cisco.ise.ups.build.WorkflowRunnerMojo.setupWorkflowEnvironment(WorkflowRunnerMojo.java:514)
        at com.cisco.ise.ups.build.WorkflowRunnerMojo.execute(WorkflowRunnerMojo.java:816)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
        ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_6da5971.Offline
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
        ... 33 more
[ERROR]
###############
```

**Steps followed:**

1. "mvn compile" .
2. "mvn org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:instrument"
3. "mvn test" - Exception raised at this step.

Please let me know of how to get rid of this exception ? Was that the right place to add classpath?? (in surefire plugin) OR should it be specified some where??

Thank you.

Comment: I'd bet that, if it is necessary to add libraries for testing, they should be specified in the `<dependencies>` section of the pom, with scope=test.

Comment: @LittleSanti: Tweaked pom.xml as per suggestion. Still issue (exception) persist. Added these lines under <dependencies> tab.               <dependency>
<groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
<artifactId>org.jacoco.agent</artifactId>
<scope>test</scope>
<classifier>runtime</classifier>
<version>0.7.7.201606060606</version>
</dependency>. **Already jacocoagent.jar was downloaded and present on disk. It is just need to make this available on classpath so that instrumented classes can initiate it** (http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/offline.html). Not sure, what still is missing !!!

Comment: I see. Well... The other solution I think of is to set that dependency within the **plugin's** dependencies, because the plugins' classloader might be different from the tested code's classloader.

Comment: @LittleSanti: In the above snippet of code , it was already mentioned in <additionalClasspathElements> . right ? Can you tell me how to add classpath in maven pom.xml?  basically, in working case., command look like this:(O/P of "ps aux | grep java")                                                                                                                              **jre/bin/java -javaagent:/root/.m2/repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.7.7.201606060606/org.jacoco.agent-0.7.7.201606060606-runtime.jar=destfile=target/jacoco.exec -jar target/surefire/surefirebooter5305632.jar**

Comment: The only ways I know to add jars to a classpath in a pom.xml are the two mentioned before: The `dependencies` node and the `plugins/pugin/dependencies` node.

Answer (score 21):

The classpath stuff on the surefire plugin is not necessary. You need to add a dependency to each module that has tests, like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.jacoco.agent</artifactId>
    <classifier>runtime</classifier>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <version>${your.jacoco.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Make sure you don't miss the "classifier" part, or it won't work.

[Full example from PowerMock project](https://github.com/powermock/powermock-examples-maven/blob/master/jacoco-offline/pom.xml)

Answer (score 3):

[dr. macphail's trance article](https://deors.wordpress.com/2014/07/04/individual-test-coverage-sonarqube-jacoco/) on getting Sonar + JaCoCo + PowerMock did the job for me:

```
  <!-- Provide information for coverage per test -->
  <profile>
     <id>coverage-per-test</id>
     <build>
        <plugins>
           <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.20</version>
              <configuration>
                 <argLine>${argLine} -Xverify:none</argLine>
                 <properties>
                    <property>
                       <name>listener</name>
                       <value>org.sonar.java.jacoco.JUnitListener</value>
                    </property>
                 </properties>
              </configuration>
           </plugin>
        </plugins>
     </build>

     <dependencies>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.sonarsource.java</groupId>
           <artifactId>sonar-jacoco-listeners</artifactId>
           <version>4.9.0.9858</version>
           <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
     </dependencies>
  </profile>
```

As mentioned in the comments section of the blog post :

> In case your default argLine is not “simple” you might need to use the following snippet:
>
> {argLine} -XX:-UseSplitVerifier
>
> Otherwise you might run into ClassNotFoundException – e.g. java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jacoco.agent.rt.RT